# Undefined method 'jobs_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner to ruby on rails and getting this error. I have no idea where's the jobs_path in there.

[image]

Here's the controller code

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(params.require(:job).permit(:title, :company, :url))
    if @job.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing a `resources :jobs` in your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks Why do we need to add resource ? confused here :) Thank you it solved the issue.

Comment: You should maybe do some reading on [rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) -- the concept is kind of fundamental to the framework.

Comment: Some tips on how to ask a good question: Copy the error messages and add it to your question. Don't take a screenshot of error messages or code in your editor because it cannot be searched. Don't use the code snippet function for code which is not html/javascript and meant to be run as demo like a jsfiddle.

Comment: @max Thanks for the suggestion I will do that from next time.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look a little bit at what is going on here:

```
<%= simple_form_for @job do |form| %>
```

Creates a html `<form>` form tag. Forms as we already know have a `action` attribute which should contain an URL where the browser sends the data.

SimpleForm takes a look at the model passed as the first argument and says ah, a Job model, I bet new jobs are created with the `JobsController` and `POST /jobs`. Since Rails automatically creates `*_url` and `*_path helper` functions SimpleForm assumes you have set up the route properly and tries to call `jobs_path` to use for the action attribute.

### Set up the route

Rails has a routing method named `resources` which will do about 90% of your rails routing. It creates a full set of CRUD routes and is very customizable. Read up on it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

```
resources :jobs
```

By running `$ rake routes` we can see that it generates the following routes:

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
    jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)          jobs#index
         POST   /jobs(.:format)          jobs#create
 new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)      jobs#new
edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format) jobs#edit
     job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#show
         PATCH  /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#update
         PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#update
         DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#destroy
```

Pay attention to the prefix column on the far left. It tells you what the helper methods will be called (`new_job_path` and `edit_job_url` for example).